# mongodb: how to write below query string

Tags: mongodb

I want to select all the records that meet below criteria:

```
if "used1" not in record or record["used1"] != True
```

How to write this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use [`$exists`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists) for the first:

```
db.collection.find({ used1: { $exists: false } })
```

and [`$ne`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24ne) for the second:

```
db.collection.find({ used1: { $ne: true } })
```

To combine them, use [`$or`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or):

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [
        { used1: { $exists: false } },
        { used1: { $ne:     true  } }
    ]
 })
```